# Space after array_rand

Tags: php

I have a php script that is generating random quotes from txt files:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
$lin1 = file('1.txt');
$first = $lin1[array_rand($lin1)];
$lin2 = file('2.txt');
$secound = $lin2[array_rand($lin2)];
$lin3 = file('3.txt');
$thi = $lin3[array_rand($lin3)];

echo "$first-$secound-$thi<br>";
}
?>
```

The txt files looks like this:

```
We
They
Them
```

What I expect in output is something like this:

```
We-are-blue
```

But what I get is this:

```
We -are -blue
```

The script is adding space after $first, $secound and $ thi. How to eliminate this space?

Comment: Did you try using ```trim()```? Like: ```echo trim($first).'-'.trim($secound).'-'.trim($thi);```

Comment: WOW that was fast, 26 seconds and working, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please replace

echo "$first-$secound-$thi
";

To

echo trim($first).'-'.trim($secound).'-'.trim($thi).'
';

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for `file`:

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds
>   to a line in the file, with the newline still attached.

You have an array of strings with ending `\n`, so you need to trim data:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $lin1    = file('1.txt');
    $first   = trim($lin1[array_rand($lin1)]);
    $lin2    = file('2.txt');
    $secound = trim($lin2[array_rand($lin2)]);
    $lin3    = file('3.txt');
    $thi     = trim($lin3[array_rand($lin3)]);

    echo "$first-$secound-$thi<br>";
}
```